# Parsifal installation error

Tags: parsing, makefile, installation, ocaml

I have a problem with running the make of [parsifal](https://github.com/ANSSI-FR/parsifal) (parser)

```
sed -i -e "s+^\(.*\.cm. *\):+build/\1:+" -e "s+ \([^/ ]*\.cm.\)+   build/\1+g" build/.depends
sed: -e: No such file or directory
make[1]: *** No rule to make target `build/.depends', needed by `depends'.  Stop.
make: *** [libs] Error 1
```

Someone can help me with this error?

I am on mac 10.12.2 and ocaml version 4.02.3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This command is written for the Linux version of sed. macOS has the Berkeley version of sed. The Berkeley `-i` flag requires an argument telling what extension to use for a backup of the in-place modification. You could try editing the line so it says something like this:

```
sed -i .bak -e <AND SO ON>
```